# Is the $H^1$ norm multiplicative? (otherwise, how to get the inequality?)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

I have $u,v \in H^1(0,1)$ with $v(0) = 0$. I would like to get a $C >0$ such that

$$|u(1)v(1)| \le C \|u\|_{H^1} \|v\|_{H^1}$$

What I thought about was writing

$$u(1)v(1) = (uv)(1) = \int_0^1 (uv)' + (uv)(0) = \int_0^1 (uv)'$$

Thus

$$|u(1)v(1)| = \left| \int_0^1 (uv)' \right| \le \|(uv)'\|_{L^2} \le \|uv\|_{H^1}$$

At this point I'm wondering if the $H^1$ norm is multiplicative, i.e. if $\|uv\|_{H^1} \le \|u\|_{H^1} \|v\|_{H^1}$, **OR** at least if there is some $L>0$ such that for all $H^1(0,1)$ functions $w,r$, we have $\|wr\|_{H^1} \le L\|w\|_{H1} \|r\|_{H^1}$ (which seems like a weird thing, though anyway..)

Comment: Can you prove that there is a constant $C$ satisfying $|u(1)| \le C \|u\|_{H^1}$? Your result would then hold true with constant $C^2$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. not really. I can prove this for $v$, by saying $v(1) = \int_0^1 v' + v(0) = \int_0^1 v'$, then $|v(1)| \le \int_0^1 |v'| \le \|v'\|_{L^2} \le \|v\|_{H^1}$, here my constant would be $1$. Not sure how to do it for $u$.

Comment: You have $|u(x) - u(1)| \le \|u'\|_{L^2}$, so that $|u(1)| \le |u(x)| + \|u'\|_{L^2}$. Now integrate wrt $x$ and use the fact that $\|u\|_{L^1} \le \|u\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. ohh! I should've given this more thought. Nicely done!